# How to import CSS in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, css

I'd like to import a gradient in CSS (from this site http://gradientcreator.com) I tried through the "CSS Properties" panel but I can not edit. I edited SVG in notepad by putting CSS, but when I open the file in Illustrator the backgroud turns black. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<svg version="1.1" id="Camada_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1080;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
.colorful { background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, hsl(273, 95%, 74%) 0%, transparent 70%),                             
                        -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(34, 100%, 74%) 10%, transparent 80%),
                        -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, hsl(63, 96%, 68%) 10%, transparent 80%),
                        -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, hsl(29, 93%, 70%) 50%, transparent 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, hsl(273, 95%, 74%) 0%, transparent 70%), 
                        -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(34, 100%, 74%) 10%, transparent 80%),
                        -ms-linear-gradient(225deg, hsl(63, 96%, 68%) 10%, transparent 80%), 
                        -ms-linear-gradient(315deg, hsl(29, 93%, 70%) 50%, transparent 100%); 
            background: linear-gradient(45deg, hsl(273, 95%, 74%) 0%, transparent 70%), 
                        linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(34, 100%, 74%) 10%, transparent 80%), 
                        linear-gradient(225deg, hsl(63, 96%, 68%) 10%, transparent 80%),
                        linear-gradient(315deg, hsl(29, 93%, 70%) 50%, transparent 100%); } 


</style>
<g id="colorful">
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" class="st0" width="1919" height="1079"/>
<path d="M1919,1v1078H1V1H1919 M1920,0H0v1080h1920V0L1920,0z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not, the program does not have that kind of gradient primitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can import gradient as svg gradient, it rather tricky but it works:

- create svg gradient with some online tool that allows to generate svg code, for example http://angrytools.com/gradient/
- copy svg code and save it to file with svg extension.
- open illustrator->File->Place and choose svg file with gradient, gradient will be imported and applied to rectangle.
- create new gradient swatch:  select rectangle with this gradient and drag the gradient fill from the Fill box in the Gradient Tools panel or Color panel to the Swatches panel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Very interesting this site angrytools mainly because it converts the code to SVG, I see that it is not possible to paste the code CSS into the tool, you know some website that this would be possible?. Thank you.

Comment: yes, i just search in google and found http://www.kmhcreative.com/downloads/CSS2SVG.htm

Comment: svg also does not have angular gradient, but there are some workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465405/svg-angular-gradient

Comment: Please, vote up answer instead of 'thanks' :)